# escape continuously strings in regex matching in python

Tags: python, regex

I met one problem when I use regex to match some string using Python.

Example string:

> ln[1] --This is a string--
>
> ln[2] Match the line below.
>
> ln[3] --This is a string--
>
> ln[4] Match this line start from here.
>
> ln[5] -This is the end-

I want to extract abc in the string above.

code:

```
pattern = re.compile('%s(.*?)%s' % ('--This is a string--', '-This is the end-'))
re.findall(pattern, string)
```

How can I get the line 4 only, not get line 2 to line 4 ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your regex says `.*?` -- what is it that you intend?

Comment: To be fair, `abc` would work.

Comment: Regex engines work left-to-right, so your regex starts the match at the first `a` it encounters, and then keeps matching until the `c` is reached. If you don't want to allow more than one `a`, you need to tell the regex engine that.

Comment: I'd like to match only one a, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Probably, via this:

```
pattern = re.compile('.*(a.*?c)')
re.findall(pattern, string)  # yields ["abc"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> re.findall('a[^a]*c', 'aaaaaaaaabc')
['abc']
>>> re.findall('a[^a]*c', 'aaaaaaaaa c')
['a c']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace all instances of repeated characters you could use id or named groups.

Example:

with id:

```
>>> re.sub('(.)(\\1)+', '\\1', 'abcAAAAabcBBBBabcCCCCabc')
'abcAabcBabcCabc'
```

with name:

```
>>> re.sub('(?P<n>.)(?P=n)+', '\\1', 'abcAAAAabcBBBBabcCCCCabc')
'abcAabcBabcCabc'
```